# How do redirect microphone audio output to headphone output?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I'm trying to to redirect the sound that's being inputted into my microphone jack out into my headphone jack, is there any easy way to do this?

I've tried doing the following command:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

But I'm trying to hear the sound in real time, and it has a latency even if I set it as "latency_msec=0"

Any ideas?

Comment: "easy" is relative. IMO it is best to use Ubuntu studio with jack and LMMS or Ardour. What applications are you using ? See also http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration

Comment: Please update your question providing details on the sound hardware in question, and how you are configuring the loopback in Windows where you say there is no latency.

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

In a Terminal, type:

```
alsamixer
```

Then hit F6 to choose your onboard sound card.
Then F4 and set "capture" on 50%, for example.
Hit F3, go to the track "loopback" and set it on "enable".
Go to track "Mic" and set it on 100%, or any value so you can hear something.
If you still hear nothing from your microphone, stay on the track "Mic" and hit the key "m" to unmute the track.
That's it!

Works perfectly with my HDA Intel PCH.

Comment: "loopback" does not exist in that menu. Can you please correct your answer?

Comment: In my configuration I have "loopback mixing" and it works... on channel right, so it's pretty annoying to hear yourself on only one ear.

Comment: Well I have to contradict myself, now I hear myself on both channels, so yay thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless your hardware has a direct monitoring feature and can completely avoid processing the sound through software, there is going to be latency.

It sounds like you are trying to do this on standard built-in audio hardware, which requires software processing to redirect audio, therefore no, there is no way to get rid of the latency.

Comment: I don't think it's a hardware issue as I've been able to achieve no latency when using windows.

Comment: Although there will always be some latency, there are many causes and as the OP stated s/he can get the results on other OS, so it is likely a matter of configuration and applications. The problem is the default desktop is not configured for audio, see Ubuntu Studio, KXStudio - http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/ or similar (Fedora Jam) and http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration#the_kernel . We really can not offer more specific advice without additional information.

Comment: No, it is not a matter of configuration and applications. I'm not sure what was done under Windows, but I guarantee it was not zero latency, as Windows is not RT (not even the poorly named Windows RT). If one wants to make a comparison to Windows, then one should explain the configuration in Windows, in the question, and also clarify what exact hardware is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the lowlatency kernel to achieve this type of performance.

I use this kernel and the latency is so low I get realtime microphone feedback noise when the microphone is too loud without any echo, just straight-up high pitched noise like it is supposed to be.

Run the following commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
```

Reboot for the changes to take effect and don't forget to select the lowlatency kernel from the grub menu.

Also, as mentioned by bodhi.zazen, you should really consider checking out [Ubuntustudio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) as it comes pre-configured with the lowlatency kernel and all that stuff. You can always install the ubuntu-desktop after installation if you prefer the unity desktop environment.

---

Additionally, installing ubuntustudio through apt-get usually doesn't result in a system that has the full configuration that normally comes with ubuntustudio.

You can, however, get the full configuration that comes along with Ubuntustudio by running `tasksel` and choosing the "pro audio" and "audio recording" tools.

```
sudo tasksel
```

**NOTE:** [because of a bug in tasksel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645), DO NOT use tasksel to uninstall packages. ONLY use tasksel to install.

Comment: The low latency kernel is for the most part outdated with anything resembling a modern CPU with multiple cores and a modern kernel ( > 2.6.31) . See http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration#the_kernel . Ubuntu studio or KXStudio have many modifications other then a low latency kernel and the latency the OP is noticing is unlikely due to the kernel. If you have made ALL the adjustments on the page I linked, and still have a problem, then try the lowlatency kernel patch.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen What are you talking about? The lowlatency image is not outdated. It's not a preempt-rt kernel, but the preempt support is still a patch and not part of mainline. The lowlatency kernel is built using options in the mainline kernel only (minus the backport patches that every Ubuntu kernel gets).

Comment: @dobey - see the link I gave for details. the rt patch is not accepted into mainline as it has potential for instability. In the old days, processors were slower and single core. Modern processors are multicore and 100-1000 x faster then the sampling rate, so rt patch is rarely needed. It may sound coll "real time" , but modern kernels + mulitcore can keep up just fine.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You are misunderstanding the meaning of realtime, and what is or isn't needed for audio production. It's not all about the CPU itself. Anyway, it is irrelevant to the question, because we don't know what hardware is being used.

Comment: @dobey yea, I am familiar with the RT patch. It is not needed as processors are faster.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Feel free to convince jackd that my i7 4790 is fast enough, and it shouldn't be giving me xrun errors, because my CPU is fast enough.

Comment: @dobey - you know as well as I do that there are many configuration differences other then a rt kernel between ubuntu and Ubuntu studio as well as many factors to xrun errors. If the rt kernel is the only thing that is different, then sure go ahead and use it. But, in general, it is a old kernel patch and is not necessary as documented at linux musicians and by the fact the the patch is rejected upstream. http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration#the_kernel

Comment: "Kernels >= 2.6.31 seem to work pretty good without RT patch, also for real-time pro audio usage. It's not strictly necessary anymore to install a real-time ('rt') kernel to get good results." so sure if for some reason you have better results with the RT kernel patch use it, but in general it is not necessary for most people most of the time.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Again, that patch is completely irrelevant, because the lowlatency kernel doesn't use it, nor does UbuntuStudio ship it. It has never been relevant to this question, nor was it relevant to this answer to the question.

Comment: This explains the differences a little bit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel#Kernel_Types. All I know is that I use L.L. on Ubuntustudio with alsa and pulseaudio and I have really good results. I only get latency if I set latency_msec to > 0.